# How to remove the selected items of a Telerik's RadListView?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, telerik

I would like to remove the current selected items in a **[RadListView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/listview/listview)**, however, I can't find a way to do that.

This is the basic code that I tried:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub RemoveSelectedItems(ByVal sender As RadListView)

    ' Dim selectedIndices As Integer() = ...?

    For Each item As ListViewDataItem In sender.SelectedItems
        sender.Items.Remove(item)
    Next

End Sub
```

It throws an exception due to try enumerate a modified collection, I understand it, but I don't know what alternative to do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a list first and use this list to remove them... This is in C#, if you want VB I can show that as well since you tagged both languages...

```
List<ListViewDataItem> saveSelectedItems = new List<ListViewDataItem>();

foreach (ListViewDataItem eachItem in sender.SelectedItems)
{
  saveSelectedItems.Add(eachItem);
}

foreach (ListViewDataItem item in saveSelectedItems)
{
  sender.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!, I just would like to comment that a simpler or elegant way is using the .ToList method directly on the SeledItems collection.

Comment: Of course I could have put it in many other ways, but wasn't necessary ;) It was to get the point across that basically you can't modify the array while removing them...

Comment: RadListView has no property "Items"

Comment: @Gerry I beg to differ http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/listview/populating-with-data/unbound-mode . Read that directly from Telerik.

Comment: I'm working on Xamarin platform, there is no Items here.

Comment: Well that's a different story, this was for Winforms **not** Xamarin.

Comment: For xamarin forms set **SelectionMode** to **None**,Because that worked for me